# python request library giving wrong value single quotes

Tags: python, json

Facing some issue in calling API using request library. Problem is described as follows

The code:.

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(json_data), headers=headers)
```

When I perform r.text the apostrophe in the string is giving me as
like this `Bachelor\u2019s Degree`. This should actually give me the response as **Bachelor's Degree**.

I tried json.loads also but the single quote problem remains the same,
How to get the string value correctly.

Comment: `\u2019` is not an apostrophe (`'`), it's a single quotation mark (`’`). also: '\u2019' is as much a different string from '’' as`IV` is a different number from `4`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you see here (`"Bachelor\u2019s Degree"`) is the string's inner representation, where `"\u2019"` is the [unicode codepoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) for "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK". This is perfectly correct, there's nothing wrong here, if you `print()` this string you'll get what you expect:

```
>>> s = 'Bachelor\u2019s Degree'
>>> print(s)
Bachelor’s Degree
```

[Learning about unicode and encodings](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) might save you quite some time FWIW.

EDIT:

> When I save in db and then on displaying on HTML it will cause issue
>   right?

Have you tried ?

Your database connector is supposed to encode it to the proper encoding (according to your fields, tables and client encoding settings).

wrt/ "displaying it on HTML", it mostly depends on whether you're using Python 2.7.x or Python 3.x AND on how you build your HTML, but if you're using some decent framework with a decent template engine (if not you should reconsider your stack) chances are it will work out of the box.

As I already mentionned, learning about unicode and encodings will save you *a lot* of time.

Comment: using a quote mark instead of an apostrophe is technically wrong

Comment: Is there a possibility that I can correctly decode the string?

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW you have nothing to "decode" here, your string is ok, just use it.

Comment: When I save in db and then on displaying on HTML it will cause issue right?

Comment: Basically, I am developing API and my team will integrate the API

Comment: @AKHILMATHEW what I meant was: have you tried saving this to your database and displaying it on your front ?

Comment: Fine. So what about learning about unicode and encodings now ?

Answer (score 1):

It's just using a UTF-8 encoding, it is not "wrong".

```
string = 'Bachelor\u2019s Degree'
print(string)
Bachelor’s Degree
```

You can `decode` and `encode` it again, but I can't see any reason why you would want to do that (this might not work in Python 2):

```
string = 'Bachelor\u2019s Degree'.encode().decode('utf-8')
print(string)
Bachelor’s Degree
```

Comment: `.encode().decode('utf-8')` is entirely useless here, why even mention it (and get the order in the description wrong on top)?

Comment: Actually it's not "a UTF-8 encoding" but the unicode code point. The utf-8 encoding would be `b'Bachelor\xe2\x80\x99s Degree'`.

Answer (score 1):

From requests docs:

> When you make a request, Requests makes educated guesses about the
> encoding of the response based on the HTTP headers. The text encoding
> guessed by Requests is used when you access r.text

On the response object, you may use `.content` instead of `.text` to get the response in UTF-8